# How to initialize a vector of pair when it is typedef-ed?

Tags: c++, vector

I am starting to learn C++ here so pardon me if I am asking noob questions.
My problem is that I cannot initialize my vector of pair of strings.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > pair_of_strings;
 
int main()
{
pair_of_strings test1{
        {"hello", "world"},
        {"captain", "america"}};

return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\support\Test.cpp(15) : error C2601: 'test1' : local function definitions are illegal
C:\Documents and Settings\support\Test.cpp(15) : error C2063: 'test1' : not a function
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: It compiles with no problems under GCC 6.3.0.

Comment: Which version of Visual C++ are you using?

Comment: Works for me too. But you should use `#include <cassert>` instead of `#include <assert.h>`.

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a3fa8cb8db6f869)

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual C++.

Comment: And which *version* of it? Which *release*? 2017? 2015? 2013? Something older? I matters because older versions didn't support the C++11 standard (or later, of course) and so can't handle initializer lists like yours for the `test1` variable.

Comment: Of which there are, I think, 15 major versions and countless service packs and patches. Which version of Visual Studio you are using may matter.

Comment: Works for me on msvc. Did you mistype some parentheses in your code, but not put them here?

Comment: btw the `typedef` is a red herring. A typedef creates an alias that behaves exactly as if you had typed the original type.

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs. I was using MV C++ 6.0 1994-98 @_@ I tried online GNU compiler and now works fine.

Comment: Would recommend declaring `using namespace std;` on top .. makes code more readable and less cryptic : `typedef vector<pair<string, string> > pair_of_strings;`

Comment: @Zakir `using namespace std;` is a bad habit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721

Comment: @aschepler: Thanks - never thought of it that way !!